# History command in redhat linux

Tags: linux, redhat

Guys please I am new to linux . I want to know the current size of the history ( I am not using bash history ) I google it but I found nothing useful thanks in advance

Comment: Whose history do you want to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the environment variable  :

```
echo $HISTFILESIZE
```

Comment: Could you tell me please how to increase or change it ??

Comment: Also u can change it by editing .bashrc file.